# Universal container conversion? if from Foldable to Alternative?

Tags: haskell, containers, applicative, foldable, alternative-functor

For `instance Alternative []`, `(<|>) = (++)`. So I regarded `(<|>)` as some kind of splicer, resulting in seemingly almost-universal container converter:

```
-- (<|>) = generalization of (++)

(<|) :: Alternative f => x -> f x -> f x
x <| xs = pure x <|> xs

conv :: (Foldable t, Alternative f) => t x -> f x
conv = foldr (<|) empty
```

Indeed, I was able to generalize *all* functions from `Data.List`, here's some:

```
-- fmap = generalization of map

reverse :: (Foldable t, Alternative f) => t a -> f a
reverse = getAlt . getDual . foldMap (Dual . Alt . pure)

-- asum = generalization of concat

asumMap :: (Foldable t, Alternative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f b -- generalization of concatMap
asumMap f = getAlt . foldMap (Alt . f)

splitAt :: (Foldable t, Alternative f, Alternative g) => Int -> t a -> (f a, g a)
splitAt n xs = let (_,fs,gs) = foldl' (\(i,z1,z2) x -> if 0 < i then (i-1,z1 . (x <|),z2) else (0,z1,z2 . (x <|))) (n,id,id) xs in (fs empty,gs empty)
```

Also, this analogy makes some interesting new instances, such as a working applicative functor for functor sums (`Data.Functor.Sum`):

```
instance (Foldable f, Applicative f, Alternative g) => Applicative (Sum f g) where
    pure = InL . pure
    InL f <*> InL x = InL (f <*> x)
    InL f <*> InR x = InR (conv f <*> x)
    InR f <*> InL x = InR (f <*> conv x)
    InR f <*> InR x = InR (f <*> x)

instance (Foldable f, Applicative f, Alternative g) => Alternative (Sum f g) where
    empty = InR empty
    InL x <|> _ = InL x
    InR _ <|> InL y = InL y
    InR x <|> InR y = InR (x <|> y)
```

Is it actually good idea to generalize *all* functions and make new instances with this analogy, especially for list operations?

EDIT: I'm especially concerned about ambiguous return type. For normal list operations, the return type is deducible from its argument types. But the "universal" version is not, as the return type must be explicitly specified. Is this problem severe enough to regard the analogy dangerous? (Or is there any other problem?)

EDIT 2: If I'm understanding the behavior of `foldl'` exactly, the time complexity of universal `splitAt` (shown above) must be `Θ(length xs)`, as `foldl'` is strict for every elements, right? If yes, that must be a problem, as it's inferior to the regular version's `Θ(min n (length xs))`.

Comment: I voted to close as "unclear what you're asking".  Could you be more specific about the concerns you have, or the kind of information you are looking for in an acceptable answer?

Comment: Cf. [a recent discussion on the Libraries mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2017-November/028318.html) about a suggested `foldAlt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not always a good idea to make functions as polymorphic as theoretically possible, in particular not *function arguments*. As a rule of thumb: make function *results* as polymorphic as possible. (Often, the arguments will then already contain some type variables that are used in the result.) Only if you have a particular reason, also give the arguments extra polymorphism.

The reason being: if *everything* is polymorphic, the compiler has no hints as to what concrete types to choose. Polymorphic results/values are usually ok, because these will generally be bound directly or indirectly to some top-level definition which has an explicit signature, but polymorphic *arguments* will often only be filled with literals (number literals are polymorphic in Haskell, and strings/lists can be too) or other polymorphic values, so you end up having to type out lots of explicit local signatures, which tends to be more awkward than having to occasionally toss in an explicit conversion function because something is *not polymorphic enough*.

This idea with `Foldable->Alternative` specifically has another problem that the `Alternative` class is rather frowned upon, having no very solid mathematical backing. It's basically the class of applicative functors which for every instantiation give rise to a `Monoid`. Well, that can also be expressed directly, by demanding `Monoid` itself. The “universal container conversion function” thus already exists, it is `foldMap pure`.

Comment: What about `splitAt` I especially concerned about?

Comment: `splitAt :: f a -> (g a, f a)` I'd admit as _perhaps sensible_, but `t a -> (f a, g a)` definitely not because you want to be able to split off _k_ chunks of _l_ elements each from a list in _O_ (_l_ ⋅ _k_) time, even if the list is infinite. If the RHS would each time have to be nop-converted, this would become _O_ (_l_ ⋅ _k_ ²)

Comment: `Foldable` itself is arguably an argument for polymorphic arguments: the container type appears only in the arguments of the methods. I guess we're just lucky people aren't doing too much folding over `Corecursive` or `Unfoldable` things.